# Issue with autocomplete using AJAX call in JSON format

Tags: ajax, autocomplete

I am trying to call JSON data using AJAX call as shown below in my input filed using autocomplete ...

But it is not returning/suggesting any values..when i debug it is going to the sucessmodule also..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function log( message ) {
      $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
      $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }
$( "#city" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
         'async': false, 
                'global': false, 
      url: "webservice?$top=10&$format=json",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        featureClass: "P",
        style: "full",
        maxRows: 12,
        term: request.term
      },
      success: function( data ) {

        response( $.each( data, function(i, results ) {
          return {
            label: results.CITY,
            value: results.CITY
          }
        }));
      },
    });
  },
  minLength: 2,
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    log( ui.item ?
      "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
      "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
  }, 
  open: function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
  },
  close: function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
  }
});
```

data returning from the AJAX call is in the below format:

```
{"d":{"results":[{"__metadata": {"uri":"webservice('9424951638763661')","type":"arn.app.WebContent.data.LOCType"},"GID":"942495163876361","USER":"ARN","CITY":"Los Angels","},{"__metadata": {"uri":"webservice('9424951638763662')","type":"arn.app.WebContent.data.LOCType"},"GID":"942495163876362","USER":"ARN","CITY":"San Diago"}]}}
```

Can someone suggest what is wrong is the above code..

Answer (score 0):

### [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D8EDF/)

***NOTE:** The `json` variable i'm using has an escaped string you don't need this part, or the `$.parseJSON` function.*

**JS:**

```
var json = "{\"d\":{\"results\":[{\"__metadata\": {\"uri\":\"webservice(\'9424951638763661\')\",\"type\":\"arn.app.WebContent.data.LOCType\"},\"GID\":\"942495163876361\",\"USER\":\"ARN\",\"CITY\":\"Los Angels\"},{\"__metadata\": {\"uri\":\"webservice(\'9424951638763662\')\",\"type\":\"arn.app.WebContent.data.LOCType\"},\"GID\":\"942495163876362\",\"USER\":\"ARN\",\"CITY\":\"San Diago\"}]}}";

var result = $.parseJSON(json);

$.each(result.d.results, function(i, results ) {
    alert(results.CITY);
});
```

---

### Issue

Your data is different than what you are selecting

**Change:**

```
response( $.each( data, function(i, results ) {
```

**To:**

```
response( $.each( data.d.results, function(i, results ) {
```

**Description:**

This is because your JSON result due to ASP.NET contains a `.d` always.  Then you included a `results` element.  This will get you to your array and allow you to `$.each` on it.

---

### [jsFiddle AutoComplete Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D8EDF/1/)

```
var json = "{\"d\":{\"results\":[{\"__metadata\": {\"uri\":\"webservice(\'9424951638763661\')\",\"type\":\"arn.app.WebContent.data.LOCType\"},\"GID\":\"942495163876361\",\"USER\":\"ARN\",\"CITY\":\"Los Angels\"},{\"__metadata\": {\"uri\":\"webservice(\'9424951638763662\')\",\"type\":\"arn.app.WebContent.data.LOCType\"},\"GID\":\"942495163876362\",\"USER\":\"ARN\",\"CITY\":\"San Diago\"}]}}";

var result = $.parseJSON(json);
var autocompleteArray = [];
$.each(result.d.results, function(i, results ) {
    autocompleteArray.push(results.CITY);
});

$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: autocompleteArray
});
```

---

### [jsFiddle Example For you](http://jsfiddle.net/D8EDF/2/)

```
var json = "{\"d\":{\"results\":[{\"__metadata\": {\"uri\":\"webservice(\'9424951638763661\')\",\"type\":\"arn.app.WebContent.data.LOCType\"},\"GID\":\"942495163876361\",\"USER\":\"ARN\",\"CITY\":\"Los Angels\"},{\"__metadata\": {\"uri\":\"webservice(\'9424951638763662\')\",\"type\":\"arn.app.WebContent.data.LOCType\"},\"GID\":\"942495163876362\",\"USER\":\"ARN\",\"CITY\":\"San Diago\"}]}}";

var result = $.parseJSON(json);
var autocompleteArray = [];
$.each(result.d.results, function(i, results ) {
    autocompleteArray.push(results.CITY);
});
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            'async': false, 
            'global': false, 
            url: "webservice?$top=10&$format=json",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                featureClass: "P",
                style: "full",
                maxRows: 12,
                term: request.term
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                response( $.each( data.d.results, function(i, results ) {
                    return {
                        label: results.CITY,
                        value: results.GID
                    }
                }));
            },
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( ui.item ?
            "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
            "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
    }, 
    open: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
    },
    close: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry it was my mistake the JSON data is not having "," and its a proper JSON data only..Thanks

Comment: My actual issue is not with ajax but unable to see the autocomplete functionality working in my application.

Comment: Yeah that should be the `data.d.results` issue.  if not i'll happily make you a demo example.